# formatting dijit.form.DateTextBox

Tags: dojo

I am working with the Dojo `dijit.form.DateTextBox` widget.
My customer would like to display the dates as `dd-MMM-yyyy` (13-Dec-2012). This is not a problem. However, he would like to be able to use the keyboard to make entries using `ddMMyyyy` format. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

how about setting the `constraints`-property of the `dijit.form.DateTextBox` like that when instaciationg it:

```
var dateTextBox = new dijit.form.DateTextBox({
    value: new Date(),  // or what ever
    constraints: {datePattern: 'ddMMyyyy'}
});
```

Comment: this will allow entry as ddMMyyyy, but what how would I display the field as dd-MMM-yyyy?

Comment: i guess thats [impossible](http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m7s4etto9D1rblq0ko1_1280.jpg)